# The difference between authentication protocols and authentications rules

Tags: authentication

ISO 25023 divides the authenticity into authentication protocols and establishment of authentication rules. I understand that the authentication protocols aim to authenticate the user using different methods such as ID/password.

I hope that someone explain to me the difference between authentication rules and protocols.

Comment: I think it may be the other way around, take a look at this: https://www.websense.com/content/support/library/web/v78/wcg_help/auth_rules.aspx. Authentication protocol is more like PAP for example (what protocol is used for authentication) for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two notions may indeed be confusing since by definition a protocol is itself a set of rules. But in case of ISO/IEC 25023 the meanings are  different and I think the best definition could be a tangible example:

Suppose you use any authentication protocol that uses ID/Password method as you said: the authentication rules could be, for example, a set f these ones:

- The password must be hashed
- The inputs must be sanitized to prevent SQL injections
- The ID must be number
- The ID must not exceed 25 digits
- ...

An authentication rule is a set of measures taken to deploy the authentication protocol in practice.